# Make my methods generic in interface or have as many as I want

Tags: android, generics, post, callback, retrofit

```
 @POST("/public/login")
void postlogin(
        @Body Login login,
        Callback<LoginResponse> response
);

@POST("/public/registration")
void postregestration(
        @Body Regestration regesteration,
        Callback<RegestrationResponse> response
);
```

I have these two methods,should I combine them both and make a generic Post function, or just leave like this for better readability. "
If I have to make generic, how can I achieve that ? because my callback expects a particular response.

I am new to retrofit,so any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep them separate.

Retrofit's goal is mapping your remote server API to a Java API. In this case, your server has two endpoints which do two very different things. It would make sense then for the interface to have two methods which correspond to those two very different things.

Comment: I have a lot of POST request to same endpoint with different Body. How can I use Generic to make only interface for these request?